# Как перенаправить вывод запущенного процесса linux в файл?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

Запустил процесс копирования файлов rsync. Потом сделал Ctrl+Z, bg, disown и закрыл терминал.
Можно ли как-то направить вывод этого уже запущенного процесса в файл, не останавливая сам процесс?
Я знаю как это сделать при запуске, а вот если процесс уже запущен.

Comment: [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1323999/4041128) вроде есть ответ + можно на [эту утилитку](http://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/) посмотреть

Comment: Попробуйте 
nohup command > file 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

Я очень люблю использовать `screen`. Лог пишется в файл и можно вернуться в приложение.

1. `screen`;
2. Запустить `rsync`;
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> — detach;
4. `screen -ls` — посмотреть список запущенных screen;
5. `screen -r` — resume;

Comment: Вопрос был о другом. Верный [ответ](https://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/) дал в своем комментарии [@BOPOH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh)

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать только если подключиться к процессу через gdb и выполнить:

- p dup2(open("/dev/null", 0), 1) # STDOUT
- p dup2(open("/dev/null", 0), 2) # STDERR
- отключиться
- выйти

Например:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/lastlog &
[1] 5636

$ ls -l /proc/5636/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 3 -> /var/log/lastlog

$ gdb -p 5636
GNU gdb 6.8-debian
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Attaching to process 5636
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/tail...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/librt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x7f3c8f5a66e0 (LWP 5636)]
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

(no debugging symbols found)
0x00007f3c8eec7b50 in nanosleep () from /lib/libc.so.6

(gdb) p dup2(open("/путь/до/файла",0),1)
[Switching to Thread 0x7f3c8f5a66e0 (LWP 5636)]
$1 = 1

(gdb) p dup2(open("/путь/до/файла",0),2)
$2 = 2

(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /usr/bin/tail, process 5636

(gdb) quit

$ ls -l /proc/5636/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 2 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 3 -> /var/log/lastlog
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 4 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 myuser myuser 64 Feb 27 07:36 5 -> /dev/null
```